# How to handle state variables in Java8 parallel streams?

Tags: java, java-8, reactive-programming

We are processing stream of events using the chain of operations in Java8 streams. As part of processing, we want to track count of events and their status for testing and monitoring purpose. Here is the simplified example of our use case that prints day of week for given date streams.

```
public class StreamStateHandling {

   private static enum Status {RECEIVED, SUCCESS, ERROR};

   private Map<Status,Integer> results = new EnumMap<>(Status.class);

   private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");


   private static Optional<LocalDate> parseDate(String dateString){
    LocalDate localDate = null;
    try {
        localDate = LocalDate.from(formatter.parse(dateString));
    }catch (DateTimeParseException e){
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    return Optional.of(localDate);
   }

   private void doWork(){
    Stream.of("12/31/2014",
            "01-01-2015",
            "12/31/2015",
            "not a date",
            "01/01/2016")
            //.parallel()
            .peek(v -> addResult(Status.RECEIVED))
            .map(StreamStateHandling::parseDate)
            .peek(v -> {if (!v.isPresent()) addResult(Status.ERROR);})
            .filter(Optional::isPresent) 
            .map(Optional::get)
            .map(DayOfWeek::from) 
            .peek(v -> addResult(Status.SUCCESS))
            .forEach(System.out::println); 

       System.out.println(results);
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new StreamStateHandling().doWork();
  }

  private void addResult(Status status){

    int current = results.getOrDefault(status, 0);
    results.put(status, current + 1);
  }
}
```

Basically we are tracking status count in a Map. This works fine in single-threaded processing but produces non-deterministic output in parallel streams.

In real world, we have several statuses and chain of operations. In general, what is the best way to instrument stream and track progress? Would prefer vanilla Java8 implementation, but ok if it is easier to do using a open source library.

Would appreciate your help.

Comment: `.peek.foreach` seems redundant. you can just `forEach` into a function that fulfills both roles.

Answer (score 3):

`EnumMap` is not thread-safe, and neither is the read-modify-write logic in `addResult()`. Try using the atomic [`ConcurrentHashMap.merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to increment the count:

```
private Map<Status, Integer> results = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

private void addResult(Status status) {
    results.merge(status, 1, Integer::sum);
}
```

Comment: Nice!. I don't know about `merge()` function. In real implementation, I have to track count by two dimensions and I was using google guava table which doesn't support synchronized implementation yet. In general, is this a good approach? We are trying to make it fast by using concurrent processing, but synchronizing to track states might make it slow.

Comment: @Raja I can think of a few options. a) Use `ConcurrentHashMap` with a composite key instead of a `Table`. b) Pre-populate your table with `AtomicInteger`s which can be incremented safely without locking. c) Synchronize around `addResult()`. Depending on how much processing is happening in the rest of your stream, this may be a serious parallelization bottleneck, as you mentioned.

Comment: More generally, I think it's questionable whether your scenario is a good use case for streams in general. Stream should generally have limited side effects and produce a single aggregate result. You're trying to produce multiple result values from a single stream.